# adding a class when link is clicked from Wordpress loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hyperlink

I am trying to isolate and add a class to a clicked anchor tag. The tags are getting pulled from a Wordpress loop. I can write JQuery to remove the "static" class, but it is removing the class from all tags in the div rather than just the one clicked, adding the active class for a split second, then all classes are removed when the page reloads with the new set of projects.

**Here is the WP loop**

```
<div class="more">
    <a class="static" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/work/">ALL</a>           
    <?php
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    echo '<a class="static" href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a>';
    } ?>
</div>
```

**Generates this html:**

```
<div class="more">
    <a class="static" href="#">ALL</a>
    <a class="static" href="#">Things</a>
    <a class="static" href="#"> More Things</a>
    <a class="static" href="#">Objects</a>
    <a class="static" href="#">Goals</a>
    <a class="static" href="#">Books</a>
    <a class="static" href="#">Drawings</a>
    <a class="static" href="#">Thoughts</a>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("div.more a").on("click", function () {
    $("a.static").removeClass("static");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

I have reviwed the other similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037501/javascript-add-class-when-link-is-clicked) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659077/jquery-adding-class-to-link-if-its-clicked), but neither solution is working for me. Can this be done with JQuery or should I put a  click event in the html inline anchor?

It looks like it is working just for a second until the page reloads.

I am using Chrome dev tools to view the source. It looks like it is working correctly, but when the page reloads, the "static" class gets removed from all anchor tags in the div. **Would there be a reason why the class newly added class name is getting removed after page load?**

It is loading a set of projects by passing a variable throught the url. So for instance, when you click on **Things** it is passing `?type=airports` in the url to get the specific relative posts.

**UPDATE:**

Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this. The overall goal is to show the user which link they clicked when viewing the result set. So when "THings" is clicked, the link has a green background and white type, etc. Since JQuery is removing the added class on the page reload, would php be a better solution?

**UPDATE 2**

All of the suggested code worked. Since the link is reloading the page and filtering through a url parameter, the issue is not resolved, but the answers were completely correct.

Comment: don't assume class isn't added just because you don't see visual changes. Your css rule for the class may not be specific enough in reference to other css rules that apply to element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div.more a").on("click", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("static").addClass("active");
});
```

`$(this)` means current clicked object in this case.

I cannot explain that add class not working thing. I just tried it with the latest jquery and it's working. Are you sure it's not adding active?

#### Edit

```
$(function(){
    $("div.more a").forEach(function(i){
        var active = window.location.hash;

        if($(this).text() == active){
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

And then shamelessly stealing from the answer below me by Alexander :P:

```
$("div.more a").on("click", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
  // Revert all to original state
  $("a.static")
    .removeClass("active")
    .addClass("static");
  // Set classes to clicked anchor
  $(this)
    .removeClass("static")
    .addClass("active");

  window.location.hash = $(this).text();
});
```

There try something like that. It might have a couple of errors but I'm sure with some reading you could fix them.

Edit again:

Notice the:

```
   event.preventDefault();
```

This means do not follow the link and so it will not reload the page when you click this link. I think this actually solves your problem.

Note remember to use:

```
$("div.more a").on("click", function (event) {
```

Else it won't work.

Comment: It is adding the class on click, but then it disappears when the page reloads with the new set of projects.

Comment: Of course as disclaimer JS is not supposed to be persistent, it is per load of the page and to use it otherwise is to use it outside of it's designed context as such you should really read up on what JS fundamentally is and consider your programming.

Comment: Understood. If this is not a good use of JS, what would be the better approach?

Comment: When the page refreshes it is quite obvious the user wants to start from the beginning as such you should not do anything, you should take a fresh, from server, copy of the page.

Comment: This function is still useful at times though, say you make a url of x.co.uk/project#task-123, you can use the function above (the first one) to get that # out and open the right AJAX window associated to your project that your trying to access.

Comment: Also if you do make static links to your tags then you can do the same with that too in which case the function above may not seem to crazy afterall, still I don't trust setting the url from JS

Comment: The goal is to show the user which link they have clicked on from the list. I was thinking I could add a class that shows a new background color to dictate they are currently viewing "Things", "All", etc. This seems like common web practice. If it is loading a new set of posts related to the link, it is not getting a fresh copy from the server correct? It is just using the url variable to determine which posts to load. At least that's how I thought it worked.

Comment: Do you reload the page when they click one of these links? Sounds like the set of posts etc should be load through JS AJAX, the whole page should be AJAX and JS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12953/discussion-between-carey-estes-and-sammaye)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with this:

```
$("div.more a").on("click", function () {
  // Revert all to original state
  $("a.static")
    .removeClass("active")
    .addClass("static");
  // Set classes to clicked anchor
  $(this)
    .removeClass("static")
    .addClass("active");
});
```

- Remove class `active` from all anchors.
- Add class `static` to all anchors.
- Remove class `static` from clicked anchor.
- Add class `active` to clicked anchor.

Comment: Yea taking stateful clicks into consideration this is the better option

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about dynamically generated elements, you need to use the `.on()` method (ok), but bind a click listener to `a` elements like:

```
$("div.more").on('click', 'a:not(.active)', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('static');
});
```

Using `a:not(.active)` you attach the click ev. to future elements
and you make sure the clicked one does not have already the class `active`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("div.more a").on("click", function () {
    $("a.active").removeClass("active").addClass("static");
    $(this).removeClass("static").addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to wrap your onclick function in

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

So that it listens once the document is ready. Whichever of the answers or formats you choose:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.more a").click(function () {
        $("a.static").removeClass("static");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

So simple really

Comment: That seemed like it would work. Still no luck though. All answers are adding the class succesfully until the page reloads with the new type loop.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above but none of the above solved my problem. Not because they are not good example but because I did not understand those. However I edited @Duncanmoo solution and it worked for me. This might work for you as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ul.arbetstagare a").click(function () {
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    $("a.active").removeClass("static");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});});
```